# Gradle sync failed: Illegal char <:> at index 53 - ionic capacitor

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I just finisshed creating my capacitor app which I am trying to build in android studio but every time I run this command `npx cap open android` and android studio opened I am faced with

> Gradle sync failed: Illegal char <:> at index 53:
> C:/incidentApp/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/C:-incidentApp-android-capacitor-cordova-android-plugins.iml
> (1 m 28 s 869 ms)

Could someone please tell me what this error means and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate the written file inside `c:/incidentApp/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/`. It seems that there is an invalid character `:` in the file at the position resp. character 53. Remove the illegal character in the file. It may also help if you clean your project, and then build and sync again.